# Hide "add column" in Sharepoint 2013 List

Tags: 2013, list, column, formatting, header

Is there a way to hide the last column which is always the "add column" (with a little "+" sign in it)?
I have changed the "management of content types" to "no".

I cannot (do not have access to) use SP Designer or Powershell.
It's no biggie, but I have a colored header row which looks like it is wider than the rest of the list because of that column.

One option could be just to change the color of that specific column header but I don't know how to do that either!

Answer (score 7):

The "Add a column" is related to the permissions(full control, design, etc.). Users who have contribute, read or lower access will not see this anyway. Also note this action is found in the ribbon as well.

Comment: Spot on!  I checked on a read only users computer and the header fits just fine!

Answer (score 2):

You can try below **CSS** it is working on my SharePoint online site. It will hide the last column,

```
.ms-listviewgrid .ms-viewheadertr th:last-child,
.ms-listviewgrid tr td:last-child
{
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  I've just tried that and it's not worked - just a straightforward <script> right?

Comment: You have to put the script tags in to run it.  <style type="text/css">CSS here</style>

Comment: I've tried the Style tag and the Script tag and neither has worked, I'm starting to think that perhaps it isn't a column but rather the header row overhangs the edge of the list.

Comment: Be aware, that the column "Add Column" is only displayed for users having the appropriate permission, as others already wrote. Adding the above mentioned CSS might hide the column header for this "püower" users, but other users, lacking this permission have the column not. These users with less privilegs might end up having the header of the last "real" column in the list view blended out. Not an optimal solution in my optnion. If you want to achieve the result using CSS, I suggest to use the class name of the column instead, that is 'ms-addcolumn-span'.